# How to remove rows for which the date difference is bigger or smaller than

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and they both have a datetime column.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"participant":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"3":2,"4":3},"createdOn":{"0":"2020-04-09 19:11:49","1":"2020-04-09 19:12:36","2":"2020-04-09 19:13:12","3":"2020-04-09 19:17:36","4":"2020-04-09 19:21:16"},"id_sample":{"0":20,"1":21,"2":22,"3":23,"4":24}," med":{"0":True,"1":True,"2":True,"3":True,"4":False}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"participant":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"3":3,"4":2},"createdOn":{"0":"2020-04-14 19:11:49","1":"2020-04-09 19:12:36","2":"2020-04-09 19:13:12","3":"2020-04-09 19:17:36","4":"2020-04-03 19:21:16"},"first":{"0":34.1,"1":54.2,"2":33.2,"3":54,"4":59.7}})
 

df1

participant createdOn           id_sample   med
1           2020-04-09 19:11:49    20       True
1           2020-04-09 19:12:36    21       True
1           2020-04-09 19:13:12    22       True
2           2020-04-09 19:17:36    23       True
3           2020-04-09 19:21:16    24       False


df2

participant   createdOn             first
    1         2020-04-14 19:11:49   34.1
    1         2020-04-09 19:12:36   54.2
    1         2020-04-09 19:13:12   33.2
    3         2020-04-09 19:17:36   54.0
    2         2020-04-03 19:21:16   59.7
```

I want to remove from df1 those results the date of which `createdOn` is "far" apart from any row from df2 of the same `participant` where the difference in the date is +/- 5 days.
In this case from df1 the row with `participant` 2 will be dropped because the time difference from df2 is more than 5 days.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `2020-04-09 19:11:49 34` <- what's the 34 at the end? is that supposed to be part of the timestamp?

Comment: no sorry it's not, I forgot another column

Comment: ditto df1 - missing a column

Comment: @MDR I fixed them. Thanks

Comment: Np.  Though best if you [put into the question the code to create the frames](https://pastebin.pl/view/11193b15).  Helps get better answers and so no copying mistakes are created :o).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Perform an [`outer merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) between `df1` and `df2[['participant', 'createdOn']]`:

   ```py
   df = df1.merge(df2[['participant', 'createdOn']], on='participant', how='outer', suffixes=('','2'))

   #    participant           createdOn    med          createdOn2
   # 0            1 2020-04-09 19:11:49   True 2020-04-14 19:11:49
   # 1            1 2020-04-09 19:11:49   True 2020-04-09 19:13:12
   # 2            1 2020-04-09 19:12:36   True 2020-04-14 19:11:49
   # 3            1 2020-04-09 19:12:36   True 2020-04-09 19:13:12
   # 4            1 2020-04-09 19:13:12   True 2020-04-14 19:11:49
   # 5            1 2020-04-09 19:13:12   True 2020-04-09 19:13:12
   # 6            2 2020-04-09 19:17:36   True 2020-04-03 19:21:16
   # 7            3 2020-04-09 19:21:16  False 2020-04-09 19:12:36
   # 8            3 2020-04-09 19:21:16  False 2020-04-09 19:17:36
   ```
2. Generate a `mask` where the [`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) value of the `createdOn` difference is within ([`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html)) the threshold (5 days):

   ```py
   threshold = pd.Timedelta(days=5)
   mask = df.createdOn2.sub(df.createdOn).abs().le(threshold)

   # 0     True
   # 1     True
   # 2     True
   # 3     True
   # 4     True
   # 5     True
   # 6    False
   # 7     True
   # 8     True
   # dtype: bool
   ```
3. Apply the `mask` and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

   ```py
   df.loc[mask, df1.columns].drop_duplicates()

   # participant           createdOn    med
   #           1 2020-04-09 19:11:49   True
   #           1 2020-04-09 19:12:36   True
   #           1 2020-04-09 19:13:12   True
   #           3 2020-04-09 19:21:16  False
   ```

Comment: how can I retain `first` in the end result by defining `cols = ['participant','createdOn','med', 'first']` and passing it on when applying the mask instead of  `df1.columns`?

Comment: it depends where the `first` column is. if it's like your example (`first` is only in `df2`), then it would need to be included earlier with `df2` during the `merge` step: `df = df1.merge(df2[['participant', 'createdOn', 'first']], on='participant', how='outer', suffixes=('','2'))`

Comment: Right, but actually I need to do both. Include it earlier with df2 during merge and passing `cols` when applying the mask too instead of `df1.columns`.

Comment: I have a big problem though, I get duplicates when I include column `first` . Meaning I get two rows with the same values on all other columns except column `first`

Comment: ah yeah, if now you're pulling in columns from df2, then you should use `subset` to narrow down the duplicate criteria to only consider `df1`, i.e. `df.loc[mask, df1.columns].drop_duplicates(subset=df1.columns)`

Comment: (subset=df1.columns) doesn't do the job. I was wondering if one can modify the mask so that in addition of 5 days it also checks which row of the same participant from df2 is closer in time to that row in df1?

Comment: maybe something like [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), e.g.: `df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2[['participant', 'createdOn']].sort_values('participant'), on='participant', suffixes=('','2'))`

Comment: but at this point i think the question has diverged quite a bit and should probably be posted as a new question with all the new details