# Drop rows with column value X and time difference less than Y

Tags: python, python-datetime

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840552/how-to-remove-rows-for-which-the-date-difference-is-bigger-or-smaller-than) but couldnt get to my solution.

I have a dataframe which I filtered to get rows where `df[df.columntype == 'B']` like below. Also, df.timeframe is of type datetime64[ns]

```
timeframe               columntype
292 2021-05-19 10:17:00 B
293 2021-05-19 10:18:00 B
294 2021-05-19 10:18:00 B
295 2021-05-19 10:18:00 B
296 2021-05-19 10:18:00 B
418 2021-05-25 09:49:00 B
419 2021-05-25 09:49:00 B
420 2021-05-25 09:50:00 B
659 2021-07-08 10:33:00 B
660 2021-07-08 10:33:00 B
661 2021-07-08 10:33:00 B
```

I want to drop rows where time difference is less than **5 minutes**. So I would get:

```
timeframe               columntype
292 2021-05-19 10:17:00 B
418 2021-05-25 09:49:00 B
659 2021-07-08 10:33:00 B
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do it with the method diff:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

Then filter on a condition where `df.timeframe.diff().abs() < x`

Hope it helped